# Want to load ad-less website using Python on Chrome: Disable acceptable ads for AdBlockerPlus through Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, adblock

I want to load news-websites ad-lessly on Chrome using Python-Selenium-AdBlockerPlus (APB). I can add the crx file for ABP in options. **BUT** AdBlocker has these 'Acceptable non-intrusive ads' that they let through. I can go into settings and disable it for normal browsing, but I do not know how to do it when Chrome is controlled through Selenium automation.

Note:

1. I downloaded the crx file for AdBlocker from the Chrome extensions website https://chrome-extension-downloader.com/, searching for "gighmmpiobklfepjocnamgkkbiglidom"
2. My program runs without error - I just want to add the Chrome option to disable the 'Acceptable Ads' for ABP, if it is even possible. This is my code.

```
from selenium import webdriver

EXECUTABLE = r"~/chromedriver.exe"
ADBLOCK = r"~/AdBlock –-der-beste-Ad-Blocker_v4.35.0.crx"

# set options for driver
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_extension(ADBLOCK)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = EXECUTABLE, options=options)

# get the URL
url = "https://www.dcclothesline.com/author/deangarrison/"
driver.maximize_window()
driver.implicitly_wait(30)
driver.get(url)

# calculate size of the loaded page
w2 = driver.execute_script("return document.body.offsetWidth;")
h2 = driver.execute_script("return document.body.offsetHeight;")
print("Webpage size with ad block", w2*h2)

driver.close()
```

Is there a way to do achieve it?

Comment: Does that mean you wanna simply block the ads on the web page ?

Comment: @cruisepandey yes. But with selenium